# Обработать многомерный массив stdClass foreach-ем

Tags: php, foreach

Как обработать `foreach`-ем данный массив? Не могу вывести это: `$Array[1]->EMAIL[0]->VALUE;`

```
Array (


[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TITLE] => Запрос
        [SOURCE_ID] => Веб сайт
        [DATE_CREATE] => 2016-01-14T16:34:32+03:00
        [ID] => 2394
        [EMAIL] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ID] => 6590
                        [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                        [VALUE] => pochta@gmail.com
                        [TYPE_ID] => EMAIL
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TITLE] => Запрос
        [SOURCE_ID] => WEB
        [DATE_CREATE] => 2016-01-14T17:30:33+03:00
        [ID] => 2396
        [EMAIL] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ID] => 6594
                        [VALUE_TYPE] => WORK
                        [VALUE] => pochta@mail.ru
                        [TYPE_ID] => EMAIL
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

Стандартной конструкцией

```
foreach ($array as $items){  
   foreach ($items as $value){  
      echo $value;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($array as $items)  
foreach ($items->EMAIL as $email)  
echo $email['VALUE'];

Comment: @splash58 только не `$email['VALUE']` а `$email->VALUE`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да, конечно :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас структура представлеят собой массивы объектов, поэтому на разных уровнях к элементам надо обращаться по разному. Чтобы получить то, что вы хотите циклы должны выглядеть как-то так

```
foreach ($array as $items) 
    foreach ($items->EMAIL as $email) 
        echo $email->VALUE;
```